# Finding Microsoft.Crm assembly

Tags: nuget, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm currently on a Microsoft Dynamics 2011 project, and I'm unable to find the reference to the "Microsoft.Crm", "Microsoft.Crm.Application" and "Microsoft.Crm.Dialogs" namespaces.

I searched on nuget.org without success.

Cheers

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to resolve the references? Web resource? or on a CRM form?

Comment: I'm a junior dev on a Dynamics project, and I have some code using these namespace.
The first one is an object inheriting from a Microsoft.Crm.Dialogs.ShareDialogPage object, the other is a variable of "Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Localization.Text" type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those namespaces are not listed on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/crmsdkv5_mref_reference_home(v=crm.5).aspx). Perhaps you are trying to access the core namespaces of the CRM application - in which case you shouldn't and normally wouldn't need to.

You should only use those namespaces and assemblies distributed with the [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24004).

> Namespace
>
> Microsoft.Crm.Outlook.Sdk
>
> Microsoft.Crm.Sdk
>
> Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages
>
> Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment.Proxy
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.Query
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities
>
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Designers